# How to get and perform actions of complex object in java like XML

Tags: java, xml, web-services, object

I have to create a bottom up webservice where I will create a class to accept complex object like XML as input and perform actions on it. Can you provide me a solution how to accept the complex object rather than String in java in webservice.

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String xml) {

        // My implementation to parse the xml
        return "This xml contains the following value" + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

I don't want to get the xml as string and want to use complex object. As I have to construct the String into file.xml and again parse and again convert to string.

Comment: You're gonna have to add some code of what you've tried, or approaches you've looked into, and/or more specific requirements if you want anyone to help you.  All you've really said here is "i've got a problem, does anyone have a solution?"... well, of course we don't... we don't know what your problem is

Comment: i have added the code with explanation

Comment: i guess u need to implement JAX-WS provider base webservice, which take input as source, see this sample it may be helpful https://github.com/uttesh/JAX-WS-Provider-Based-Endpoints

Comment: thanks dude as it will help me some way. But want a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Use JAXB -  with annotation you can create Objects to XML mappings and vice-versa. Usage will be similar to JPA/Hibernate Entity Annotation Mapping .

https://jaxb.java.net/

After creating mapped classes you will be able to declare methods like

```
 public MyCustomRequestResponse hello(@WebParam MyCustomRequest request) {
```